# how to execute "callOnClick()" for android API 8?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclick, imageview

I'm using "callOnClick()" in my android app

but it's suppose to support min android API 8.

how can I imitate button click un API 8?

`mSwitchBg` is of type `ImageView`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
mSwitchBg.performClick();
```

it will work from API level1

Comment: so why did they change the name?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick%28%29   check this link, it will give the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mSwitchBg.performClick()`

Comment: so why did they change the name?